# Compare instance of same class and update the old one with the new value

Tags: c#, compare, comparison, updatemodel

Compare instance of same class.

```
public class Student()
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Hobby {get; set;}
    public string Country {get; set;}
}

Student old = new Student { Name = "A", Hobby = "Swim", Country = "HK" };
Student new = new Student { Name = "A", Hobby = "Jog", Country = "US" };
```

Compare if old and new is equal, else, replace each of the field of the class that is different. Like update the old value to new one.

```
If(old != new)
{
    UpdateOldWithNew(old, new);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should create a function.... that does this? Just compare each part.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms173147(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: a generic function to update if only modified value of class?

Comment: I think compare is a confusing term: do you mean determine? also 'new' is a keyword which you are not allowed to use as a variable name ...

Answer (score 0):

```
    Student student1 = new Student { Name = "A", Hobby = "Swim", Country = "HK" };
    Student student2 = new Student { Name = "A", Hobby = "Jog", Country = "US" };   
    Student student3 = new Student { Name = "A", Hobby = "Swim", Country = "HK" };

    //reference equal 
    System.Debug.WriteLine(student1 == student2); //false
    System.Debug.WriteLine(student1 == student3); //false
    System.Debug.WriteLine(student1 == student1); //true


    if(student1 != student2)
    {
        student1 = student2;
    }
```